# Partition of graph to locate a point

Tags: algorithm, search, graph

I have an area which was already partitioned into tens of sub-areas (think like a country divided into states).

Now I have a point coordinate, what is the best algorithm to tell me which state the point in?

Of course I can match sub-area by sub-area but that's stupid because I have to search through half of them in average right?

Is there an algorithm to determine how to group several adjacent sub-area together to facilitate search, so as to optimize the number of search?

Comment: How are the sub-area boundaries described ? Do you need a raster or vector approach ? How many sub-areas, how many vertexes ?

Comment: Boundaries are described in coordinates, so there are vectors. The sub-areas are not exclusive and can be overlapped, i.e. some may included smaller ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by eliminating all areas that cannot have the point inside of them.

Let's assume that you have a 2D Cartesian coordinate system, you have a point as a 2D-vector and the areas are described as a collection of their boundary points.

Then you can sort the areas by their smallest and largest `x` and `y` coordinate (in total 4 ways of sorting). You can eliminate all areas which have their smallest `x` coordinate bigger than the `x` coordinate of your point etc.

After that, you can check the remaining polygons with a simple [ray-casting algorithm](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ray-casting_algorithm) and you should be good.

This is very efficient if you have a structure which keeps the areas sorted in all the different directions because you can eliminate the areas in logarithmic time.

Comment: Many thanks Matt, your way is much simpler. Do you have any insight if some sub-areas are actually within a bigger sub-area? Shall I pick the smallest one first, vice versa or other criteria to judge?

Comment: Well first, you need to ask yourself what is actually an area to you. To me, when you talk about an area, they cannot overlap. A bit like on a map, Monaco is not overlapping with France but it is inside France. Now if you have an area inside (completely surrounded) another area, then I think the easiest is just to check both with ray-casting or similar.